# How can I handle multiple multiple MobileCarriers in my EF Model when each Person can only have one?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-database-first

In my database-first EF model, a Person can have only one MobileCarrier.

But I'm seeing three MobileCarrier attributes in my model.  In code, p.MobileCarrier.MobileCarrierName will not work but p.MobileCarrier**2**.MobileCarrierName will.

This is very ugly and inconvenient.  And while I know I can name the attribute in my EDMX model, we are always deleting/re-generating the model so that won't work.

Any ideas how to deal?  Thanks

[image]

Comment: Your models are apparently set up incorrectly.  Its hard to say for sure since we can't see your screen.

Comment: I added the screen shot; thanks for looking at it.  Every other table has CreatedByPersonId and ModifiedByPersonId to explain all those numbers.  But the MobileCarrier2, MobileCarrier3 I don't get.  I should be able to code like I want without all the numbers just for p.MobileCarrier.MobileCarrierName.  thanks

Comment: That happens because in some way you have references to the same table from others. EF takes it as a virtual object

Comment: But MobileCarrierId as an FK is only in the model in one place (Person table) to state which mobile carrier a person uses.